# d3.js : getting the bars width or X position right?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a weird issue in my bar graph realized using d3.js: the 1 px padding between each rectangle appears irregular. I gather either or both the width or x position are the culprit but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong: the width is a fraction of the svg area and the X position is obtained via a D3 scale.

I've put a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pixeline/j679N/4/

The code ( a scale) controling the x position:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).rangeRound([padding, w - padding]);
```

The code controlling the width:

```
 var barWidth = Math.floor((w/dataset.length))-barPadding;
```

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

It's irregular because you are rounding your output range (`rangeRound`). In some cases, the distance between two bars is 3 pixels and sometimes only 2. This is because the actual `x` position is a fractional value and ends up being rounded one way in some cases and the other way on other cases.

You can mitigate the effect but changing `rangeRound` to `range`, but that won't eliminate it entirely as you'll still get fractional pixel values for positions. The best thing to do is probably to simply increase the padding so that the differences aren't as obvious.

Comment: tried that, but it's clearly unsatisfactory. Using range instead of rangeRound does not solve the issue. I guess i need to dwelve more into a custom scaling method.

Comment: As far as I can see, the issue is that if you divide the interval evenly, you end up with fractional pixel values. You could implement a custom scaling method that ensures that the distance between bars is always the same, but then the bars themselves would have different widths. If you wanted to ensure "good" values, you would have to restrict the output domain based on the number of bars etc so that the numbers add up.